# Pesquisa dinâmica ao escrever no input

Tags: jquery

Criei um sistema de paginação e de pesquisa no meu projecto. Pretendo fazer uma melhoria ao meu sistema. Quando faço uma pesquisa, só retorna resultados depois de clicar no botão pesquisar que está dentro do `form` onde criei o `input` para pesquisar.

Form:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="./busca">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">Pesquisar</label>
        <input type="text" name="busca" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Digitar...">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Na página de `busca`, tenho o seguinte código:
PHP:

```
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
if(!isset($_GET['busca'])){
    header("Location: ./recebidas");
}else{
    $valor_pesquisar = $_GET['busca'];
}

//Selecionar todos os cursos da tabela
$result_curso = "SELECT Id, De, Assunto, Conteudo, Prioridade, DATE_FORMAT(Recebido,'%H:%i') AS Hora, DATE(Recebido) AS Data,
Email, Tipo, raddb.Alertas.Para, Status FROM raddb.Alertas LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.ValAlertas
ON raddb.ValAlertas.IdSMS = raddb.Alertas.Id AND raddb.ValAlertas.Para = raddb.Alertas.Para
WHERE raddb.Alertas.Para = '$colaborador' AND De LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%'";
$resultado_curso = mysqli_query($conn, $result_curso);

//Contar o total de cursos
$total_cursos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_curso);

//Seta a quantidade de cursos por pagina
$quantidade_pg = 10;

//calcular o número de pagina necessárias para apresentar os cursos
$num_pagina = ceil($total_cursos/$quantidade_pg);

//Calcular o inicio da visualizacao
$incio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;

//Selecionar os cursos a serem apresentado na página
$result_cursos = "SELECT Id, De, Assunto, Conteudo, Prioridade, DATE_FORMAT(Recebido,'%H:%i') AS Hora, DATE(Recebido) AS Data,
Email, Tipo, raddb.Alertas.Para, Status FROM raddb.Alertas LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.ValAlertas
ON raddb.ValAlertas.IdSMS = raddb.Alertas.Id AND raddb.ValAlertas.Para = raddb.Alertas.Para
WHERE raddb.Alertas.Para = '$colaborador' AND De like '%$valor_pesquisar%' ORDER BY Recebido Desc limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
$resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);
$produto = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_cursos);
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="./busca">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">Pesquisar</label>
        <input type="text" name="busca" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Digitar...">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
    </div>
</form>
 <h1 style="font-size: 30px"><strong>Alerta Recebido</strong></h1>
    <table class="table table-responsive"> 

    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th width="20%" style="text-align:center;">De</th>
            <th width="60%" style="text-align:center;">Assunto</th>
            <th width="10%" style="text-align:center;">Prioridade</th>
            <th width="10%" style="text-align:center;">Recebido</th>                
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
        <thead>
    <?php  

        do{

         if($nomede != $produto["De"]){
    ?>  
        <th width="10%" colspan=4>Recebido: <?php echo $produto["Data"]; ?></th>
    <?php
        $nomede = $produto["De"];
        }
   ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>  
        <td ><?php echo $produto["De"]; ?></td>
        <td class="td-info view_data apagar" id="<?php echo $produto["Id"]; ?>,<?php echo $produto["Para"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal" width="20%" <?php echo $produto["Status"] != '0'?' style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 90%" ':' style="font-weight:normal; font-size: 90%" '?>><?php echo $produto["Assunto"]; ?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $produto["Prioridade"]; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $produto["Hora"]; ?></td>
        </tr>

<?php } while($produto = $resultado_cursos->fetch_assoc()); ?>
<tbody>
    </table>
<?php
                //Verificar a pagina anterior e posterior
    $pagina_anterior = $pagina - 1;
    $pagina_posterior = $pagina + 1;
?>
            <nav class="text-center">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li>
                        <?php
                        if($pagina_anterior != 0){ ?>
                            <a href="./busca?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_anterior; ?>&busca=<?php echo $valor_pesquisar; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                            </a>
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    <?php }  ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php 
                    //Apresentar a paginacao
                    for($i = 1; $i < $num_pagina + 1; $i++){ ?>
                        <li><a href="./busca?pagina=<?php echo $i; ?>&busca=<?php echo $valor_pesquisar; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php
                        if($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina){ ?>
                            <a href="./busca?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_posterior; ?>&busca=<?php echo $valor_pesquisar; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                            </a>
                        <?php }else{ ?>
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    <?php }  ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Como posso melhorar o meu sistema, de forma ao escrever no input começar logo a pesquisar na página de busca pelos resultados e retorna los com jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Então pra começar eu aconselho-te a executar o query que recupera os teus valores logo ao início da página e armanezar estes numa variável array do lado cliente com o teu jQuery

De seguida podes fazer uma pesquisa do valor dessa array com o onKeyUp event e a função `$.inArray()` do jQuery também passando como parâmetros o valor obtido da tua barra de procura e a array criada ao início

Comment: pode colocar um exemplo prático?